# MongoDB count() with multiple documents within a collection

Tags: mongodb, count

I have a collection that has the following structure

```
db.myCollection.insert({
    "VEHICLE": {
        "registration": "000XX",
        "capacity": "50000",
        "weight": "400",
        "status": "AVAILABLE"
    }
});

db.myCollection.insert({
    "EMPLOYEE": {
        "e#": "007",
        "name": "James Bond",
        "dob": "",
        "address": "England, UK",
        "hiredate": "01-APR-69",
        "position": "secret agent",
        "licence": "00001",
        "status": "AVAILABLE",
    }
});
```

I need to count the total number of **EMPLOYEES**. This has to be done **without using aggregate pipeline**. Im trying to figure out how to point the count() function to the EMPLOYEE document to count.

My research only resulted in aggregate method.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `$exists` operator to check is `EMPLOYEES` field present or not and `countDocuments` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find operation with `$exists` to get only those documents which contains EMPLOYEE key.

```
db.myCollection.find({"EMPLOYEE": {"$exists": true}}).count()
```